# iOS app Metadata rejected - Third Party issues

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, metadata, appstore-approval

"The description has been updated without any reference to third party services"

What does this error mean?  I released the app two weeks ago, made a small update, then released the updated version, and got this error:

[image]

How do I reference third party services?

Comment: What third party services are you using in your app? Are you serving ads in your app?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about App Store policies and not about programming.

Comment: @DanielStorm not about programming?  Although not your conventional stackoverflow programming question with code, this has a ton to do with app development.  The answer provided by Alexis was crucial to getting my app (which is a program) out on the app store.  My question (which is answered correctly) that I posted can definitely help other programmers/app developers in the future if they experience this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review all screenshots you submitted, all keywords you inputed as well as the description of the app. If you added an app preview video, check it too.

If on any of these metadata there's for instance a readable mention to "Android", "Windows", "Microsoft" and so on (third party = Apple's competitors), then that's why they rejected your app.

Check if you didn't violated Apple Trademarks Guidelines too (if we can read "iPhone" on the screenshots for instance)

Comment: Android was mentioned.  This solved the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Did you add anything related to this,

```
8.5
Apps may not use protected third party material such as trademarks, copyrights, patents or violate 3rd party terms of use. Authorization to use such material must be provided upon request
8.6
Apps that include the ability to download music or video content from third party sources (e.g. YouTube, SoundCloud, Vimeo, etc) without explicit authorization from those sources will be rejected
```

This is from apple rejected guidlines. Kindly refer the below link to clarification

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/